# How to draw a circle in img using php?

Tags: php, gd

How to draw a circle in (100px top and 100px left) of img using php ?

Image URL : `image.jpg`

I want to load the img then draw a circle on the orginal content of it

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at [imagefilledellipse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledellipse.php)

```
// Create a image from file.
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('imgname.jpg');

// choose a color for the ellipse
$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

// draw the blue ellipse
imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 10, 10, $ellipseColor);

// Output the image.
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: +1 just for the fact that you answered on new years eve at midnight!

Comment: is that possible draw an image circle with imagefilledellipse() function ?
I mean make a circle image from an squre image and merge it with another image.

Answer (score 5):

Start by loading the image, this function will be entirely dependant on what your source image is, but for now I'll guess it's a jpeg:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
```

Then simply create the circle on the image:

```
imagefilledellipse($img, 100, 100, 20, 20, 0x0000FF);
```

I'm not sure how you want to return it, but to output it to the browser, simply use the following:

```
imagejpeg($img);
```

Comment: Other image functions for loading are: imagecreatefromgif, imagecreatefromjpeg, imagecreatefromwbmp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(300,300); // create a 300x300 image
imagefilledellipse($img, 100, 100, 20, 20, 0x0000FF); /// draw a 20x20 circle at 100,100 using pure blue
```

Comment: I want to load the img then draw a circle on the orginal content of it

Comment: Then use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` or similar instead of the ...createtruecolor()